# Comparing VirtualBox(Ubuntu) with Actual Ubuntu

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I am having Window 7 OS with Virtual Box which has Ubuntu .
 When i am executing the code in Virtual box it takes 5.9sec . 
When i am executing the same code on actual ubuntu OS it takes 2.9sec. 
I have checked CPU info .In Virtual Box it gives CPU Speed 2968.448 MHZ and on actual ubuntu OS it gives 1600 MHz.

Can anybody pls explain the reason for this?

Comment: Virtualization is slower than bare metal.

Answer (score 0):

Cpu speed is of course not everything there is to execution of code. There is big probability that ubuntu downclocks the processor when it's not using it to save battery.

open terminal, paste this and hit enter

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq
```

Maybe [this](http://www.deltalounge.net/wpress/2012/09/virtualbox-improve-virtual-machine-performance/) helps you for increasing your performance.

Comment: Thanks Matej for reply , this command i have checked in ubuntu its giving 1600000 ...this is in Hz ??? and in Virtual Box i am unable to run this this command , there cpufreq directory does not exists

Comment: Yes, that is in Herz. You can also try this cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep mhz -i